# Inserting empty line in Java output

Tags: java, mysql

I have some code that I want to print out the entire list of classes with students in them.  I want this list to be sorted by class_id and I want to have a space between each different class.  for example:

```
100 Math Jon Doe
100 Math Tina Lee
100 Math Sally

122 Science Tom Edison
122 Science Jon Frankin
```

Right now the code is printing out correctly, except for there is no space separating the classes.

I know the error is here:

```
while(!"class_id".equals("class_id")) {
                    System.out.println("\n");

                }
```

Just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
static void listAllClasses() {
        System.out.println("\nClasses With Enrollment\n");
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ClassSelector?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "", "");
            String totalEnroll = ("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.student_x_class ORDER BY class_id");
            myStmt = con.prepareStatement(totalEnroll);

            rs = myStmt.executeQuery(totalEnroll);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String totalEnrollment = rs.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("class_name") + "\t"  + rs.getString("student_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("student_name");
                while(!"class_id".equals("class_id")) {
                    System.out.println("\n");

                }
                System.out.println(totalEnrollment);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"class_id".equals("class_id")` is always true, whatever you could do.

Comment: "if this apple is always an apple, do somethign" doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @J. Doe do you mean to print "\n" when different class_id  comes than current class_id  ?

Comment: yes, I was trying to have the code read as, "If this class_id does not equal the next class_id, insert a blank line"

Comment: I've improved my answer, could you say if one is ok?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
static void listAllClasses() {
        String currentClassId ="";
        String oldClassId = "";
        System.out.println("\nClasses With Enrollment\n");
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ClassSelector?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "", "");
            String totalEnroll = ("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.student_x_class ORDER BY class_id");
            myStmt = con.prepareStatement(totalEnroll);

            rs = myStmt.executeQuery(totalEnroll);
            while (rs.next()) {
                currentClassId = rs.getString("class_id");
                String totalEnrollment = rs.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("class_name") + "\t"  + rs.getString("student_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("student_name");
                while(currentClassId != null && oldClassId != null && !currentClassId.equals(oldClassId)) {
                    System.out.println("\n");

                }
                oldClassId = currentClassId;
                System.out.println(totalEnrollment);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String lastClass = "";
while (rs.next()) {
        String currentClass = rs.getString("class_id");
        String totalEnrollment = rs.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("class_name") + "\t"  + rs.getString("student_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("student_name");
        if(!( currentClass.equals(lastClass) || "",equals( lastClass ) )) {
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        lastClass = currentClass;
        System.out.println(totalEnrollment);
```

Answer (score 0):

`!"class_id".equals("class_id")` never happens.

What you want may be like

```
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery(totalEnroll);
        String prevClassID = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            String curClassID = rs.getString("class_id");
            String totalEnrollment = curClassID + "\t" + rs.getString("class_name") + "\t"  + rs.getString("student_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("student_name");
            if (prevClassID != null && !curClassID.equals(prevClassID)) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.println(totalEnrollment);
            prevClassID = curClassID;
        }
```

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly!  Could you explain whats happening a little, though?

Comment: Save the `class_id` just printed; for each new item, if the `class_id` is different from previously saved string, print an empty line.